# Reverting Vue B-Modal from using event.preventDefault() to original state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have this kind of component in my Vue project

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    ref="modalDialog"
    class="-modal"
    scrollable
    hide-footer
    :visible="visible"
    @hide="afterHide"
    @show="beforeShowHandler"
  >
    <...
    />
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Component',
  
  data () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {

    afterHide() {
      this.items = []
    },

    beforeShowHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (!this.items.length) {

        try {
          // Perform async checks or operations
          this.loadValues(this.context).then(result => {
              // If the condition for preventing the modal opening is met
          if (result !== 0) {
            this.$refs.modalDialog.show();
          } else {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
              this.$bvModal.hide('modalDialog')
            })
          }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in beforeShowHandler:', error);
        }
      } else {
        ...
      }
    },
    ....

  }
}
</script>
```

So the idea is:

When someone tries to show this dialog, the method `beforeShowHandler` is called.
If we already load a value, show dialog as usual, else, stop the model from showing and load values. If there are values, call show dialog. This will call this method again but this time values are set so it will open.

### Problem:

This works well if there are values. But: If I open dialog without values, it calls `beforeShowHandler`, and the method stops the model from opening with event.preventDefault(), call API, and get empty results. and stop the method.

After this, the model component stays in some state where I can't open it again. If I try to open the model again the method `beforeShowHandler` is never called.

How to 'reverse' the event.preventDefault() to revert the model to the original state.